# Python: class object is instantiated but not defined?

Tags: python, oop, global-variables, instance

In the last line I get the error that my object ant003 is not defined. But why?

```
class Ant:

    def __init__(self, name):
        """Initializes the data."""
        self.name = name
        self.food = 0
        self.posx = 0
        self.posy = 0
        print("(Initializing {0})".format(self.name))

    def searchFood(self):
        self.food = self.food + 1
        print("Ant {1} has {0} food.".format(self.food, self.name))


ant001 = Ant("Anton")
ant001.searchFood()
ant002 = Ant("Bob")

ants = {'ant003': None, 'ant004': None}
for name in ants.keys():
    ants[name] = Ant(name)
    print ants[name]

#print ant001
#print ant003

ant003.searchFood()   #　NameError: name 'ant003' is not defined
```

Comment: Um, because you didn't define any variable called `ant003`?

Comment: I thougt ants[name] = Ant(name) will do this.

Comment: ants[name] just holds a reference to an object of type `Ant`, It doesn't declare a variable visible in the global namespace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting an item of a dictionary does not affect namespace that contains the dictionary.

You can access dictionary value using [`dict[key]`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes#dict):

```
ants['ant003'].searchFood()
```

---

Did you mean to use [`globals`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#globals)? (not recommended)

```
...
for name in ants.keys():
    globals()[name] = Ant(name) # <----

ant003.searchFood()
```

Comment: Isn't using globals unsafe and discouraged in general?

Comment: @volcano, Yes, it is.